# Not make Window Active on Button Press

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any means to make it so that a WinForms Window will not be switched to the active window if you click on a button? I am trying to make a program that will assist with entering long strings of text for you and such when you click on a button. However, if you click on one of these buttons it will switch to my program and it won't type the text properly.

Edit:

I was able to somewhat do this by doing the following. However, there is a problem since it won't activate the window if I click on the Titlebar. So I guess what I am looking for is something that will still let me process the button click but not activate the window.

```
const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams ret = base.CreateParams;
        ret.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/09/29/475564.aspx:

```
private const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021, MA_NOACTIVATE = 0x0003;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
  if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE) {
     m.Result = (IntPtr)MA_NOACTIVATE;
     return;
  }
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Tried it out just to make sure, and it will still activate if you click on an anything other than the empty space. Not exactly what I am looking.

Comment: I'd assume that if you use button controls with their own window handles, you need to intercept the wndproc for those.

Comment: @EricLaw, Is there a specific WndProc message I would need to intercept for the button? I added this to a custom button and it still makes the form active.